# Problems installing Windows SDK 7.1 for dot.net Framework 4.0 / 2 Problems in 1

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-4.0, jenkins, sgen

Since yesterday I try to install Windows SDK 7.1 for dot.net Framework 4.0 on my windows 7 x64 
machine. I get everytime the same Error during the installation.

Error message:

```
"Installation of the "Microsoft WIndows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the
following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information"
```

Thats a pretty unhelpful error message, so I browsed the www about more information and did the suggested steps peoples recommend.
I opened the View Log and get the same return error like others.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x86.exe installation failed with the return code 5100"
```

I tried all that stuff that Microsoft, MSDN and others recommended but nothing works for me.

Stuff i tried to resolve the problem:

- Deinstallation of the Document Explorer (recommended by msdn)
- Deinstallation of the lastest Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redist x64/x86 Versions (microsoft)
- Deinstallation of Microsoft Windows SDK Windows 7 (dot.net 3.5)
- Installation of Microsoft Windows SDK 8

but like i said nothing helps :/ I get everytime the same Error message during the Installation.

other facts about my system:

- I have a lot of several Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redist versions on my system
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2008 Standard Edition enu x64/x86
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008

*Background info:*

I installed Jenkins as Service on my machine Windows 7 x64. We did a changeover from dot.net Framework 3.5 to dot.net Framework 4.0.
But the problem was that sgen.exe sends an error:

`"SGEN : error : An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format.."` (to find in build log).
Windows SDKs containing the sgen.exe in their bin folders like "C:\Program Files\Microsofft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin".
So I thought the SDK is out of date (v7.0a) and i tried to install the Windows SDK v7.1 for dot.net Framework 4.0.
May installing the latest Visual Studio version on my system could help to resolve the problem, because it should simultaneously install Windows SDKs.

But i wouldn't like to install Visual Studio on it to prevent wasting a license because nobody works on this computer.

Comment: Uninstall any existing Visual C++ 2010 redistributable and try again...For me it seems like that is what causing the issue.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this link as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901279/windows-7-sdk-installation-failure

Comment: @Ramhound: against 7.1

Comment: @Kokulan Eswaranathan: try to uninstall but dosen´t work.

Comment: @Kokulan Eswaranathan: thanks for the link, will try it.

Comment: @Kokulan Eswaranathan: Solution in Link dosent work :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the Problem by installing .Net 4.5 and SDK 7.0.
Additionally set **SdkToolsPath** to `$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)` (find in WINDOWSDIR\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets)

... all in all a strange stituation with the SDK. Leaves a bad feeling.

Comment: I have a similar problem. However, there are several instances of **SdkToolsPath** in that file. Should I change all of them? The instance in the **LC** markups has already set to **$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)**. Thanks.

Comment: Hi imriss. In the special context on the jenkins server I set all (in my case 5) SdkToolPath to $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory). On my "normal" development machine $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory) is only set in LC. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to install SDK7.0/NET3.5, but there has been no luck with SDK7.1/NET4.0. Do you have a download link to SDK7.0/NET4.0? Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't a download file - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing the windows SDK 7.1, vcredist_x86 installation failed although when i looked at the unistall a program tab of the control panel no VC 2010 x86 redist was installed. I also had the windows 7.0 SDK installed. It turns out, there is a registry key describing if and which version of the vc 210 x86 redist is installed:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86
```

The key is Installed
Mine was at 1 even if the uninstall tab did not show it, i set it to 0 it did not solve the problem, but deleting the whole

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86
```

did.
Hope it helps, I recommend you backup your registry before doing that. 
I find it deeply astonishing that Microsoft would release a SDK with such a problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding your Solution.