# how to install node js canvas on windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, canvas, cairo

I'm trying to get working canvas on node js. I'm using Windows Vista. After basic approach `npm install canvas` failed (see error below), I have looked up some tutorials, here is what I have tried:

sources:
[installing-node-canvas-for-windows](https://github.com/benjamind/delarre.docpad/blob/master/src/documents/posts/installing-node-canvas-for-windows.html.md)
[LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows)

- I have installed older Python (2.7.5) and add it to PATH (and remove Python 3.2. from PATH)
- I have checked that I do have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed
- I have downloaded the 'all in one' GTK package from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip, unziped it in C:\GTK\ and add 'C:\GTK\bin' to PATH

log in console (after running `npm install canvas` in cmd):
log contains several warnings, I don't thing these are the problem - it is mostly something like 'conversion from double to float', and one error marked in red color:

```
init.cc
d:\pathToApp\node_modules\canvas\src\PNG.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot
open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory [d:\pathToApp\n
ode_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
```

And at the very end of log there is:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6002
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd d:\pathToApp\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.16
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

After that, nothing appeared in node-module folder (no canvas subdirectory, npm after unsuccessful installation removed the subdirectory).

So I have also tried to download canvas module manually from github, unzip it in node-modules and then run `node-gyp configure` in node-modules/canvas with success, and `node-gyp build`, which unfortunatelly gave me the same error `Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h'`.

I have read everything that I found on this carefully. If you can suggest any help, please do it.

Comment: are you 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: any solutions to this

Comment: 32 bit | 
no solutions, after some time I gave up (using ubuntu)

Comment: I have managed to get it working on Windows 8 (see description bellow). I am also sorry that I cant accept any solution, but this question seems to have no "the only right one" answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to get it working on my new Windows 8 machine, so I want to share some details that can be helpful to others.

I am using:

- Windows 8.1 (64 bit)
- Visual Studio 2013 (update 2)
- Python 2.7.8
- GTK for Windows 64 bit (http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php)
- node 0.10.28
- node-gyp 1.0.1

### Procedure

Be sure to have **Python 2** and **GTK\bin** in your path.

I have downloaded files manualy from https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas and saved it to **node_modules/canvas**.

Then I run `node-gyp configure build` in canvas directory. Errors occured. I had to edit **binding.gyp** (https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/binding.gyp) in order to match actual files in GTK folder.

For example:

- line 59: "(GTK_Root)/lib/libpng.lib" -> "(GTK_Root)/lib/libpng.dll.a"
- line 34: "(GTK_Root)/bin/libpng14-14.dll" -> "(GTK_Root)/bin/libpng15-15.dll"
- ...

There can be more, you should be able to read which files are making problems from error log and then edit the names to match files in GTK folder.

After editing binding.gyp, command `node-gyp configure build` finished successfuly. Although I am not able to work with some jpg files in Canvas (I have not tested it properly), png files work fine.

### If node-gyp fails

It can happen to you, that every node-gyp command fails with message (possibly marked in red) similar to:

*"...bcrypt_lib.vcxproj(47,46): error MSB4025: Could not load file project. An invalid character for the specified encoding., Line 47, position 46."*

It it most probably because you have special character in the name of your user folder. (The fact, that Windows 8 automatically creates the name of your user folder from your first name is the lamest thing about Win 8).

2 quick solutions:

- create another user with normal (without special characters) name a and run `node-gyp configure build` from that account
- use this quick fix (it has worked for me): https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/pull/366

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/234, combining these posts helped. "Same issue here but was fixed by moving the GTK folder to C:/GTK. I had the folder in a different location and binding.gyp is looking for it in here 'GTK_Root%': 'C:/GTK', # Set the location of GTK all-in-one bundle

Also one more thing I had VS2012 installed and so I had to use the --msvs_version=2012 flag"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working on windows after a long arduous process.  I have a last couple of suggestions that you might try that I had on my list.

Copy all the dll files from c:\GTK to the canvas\build\Release folder.

Copy IEShims.dll from c:\program files(x86)\Internet Explorer to the canvas\build\Release folder.

Then run node-gyp build.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you. Before I try I have to ask, do I have to create the folders canvas\build\Release? (So I should download `canvas` module manually as I tried as second approach?) Because as I mentioned, npm removes everything after fail.

Comment: Not sure. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Did not work =(. I downloaded canvas module, unziped and 1) created folders manually and copied the files there, or 2) run node-gyp configure and copied the files there, and then in both cases run eventually node-gyp build, still the same error. (I also tried to create folders, copy the files there and then run npm install canvas) But thank you anyway! If something else comes to your mind, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Any update or resolution for this?  I'm having the same issues right now and am forced to simply create the canvas on the client side and use `toDataUrl` and download/save each file.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into trouble with canvas while trying to install [paperjs](http://paperjs.org).

Here's what worked for me.

#### My specifics

- Windows 7 x64
- node-v0.10.26-x64
- [GTK+ 2.22 x64](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win64/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101229_win64.zip)

#### GTK

Make sure you read the README. There are necessary instructions here that I overlooked the first time around. For instance:

> Run: `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`
>
> Run: `gtk-demo` and verify that it works

Running `pkg-config` let me know that I needed to have `<GTK Directory>\lib\pkgconfig` in the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.

#### canvas

I used this as a guide:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows

*NOTE: I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 installed on my machine, so I didn't have to deal with MSVC dependencies.*

`npm install canvas` was always failing - and cleaning up after itself (the jerk) - so I grabbed the cached version from the npm-cache:
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\canvas\1.1.3\package`. Copy this directory to your project's `node_modules` directory and rename it `canvas`. Enter the newly created `canvas` directory on the command line.

Run `npm install nan`.

Before you you can run `node-gyp configure` successfully, you need to verify your GTK path in `binding.gyp`

On line 5:

> 'GTK_Root%': 'C:/GTK', # Set the location of GTK all-in-one bundle

Now you can try `node-gyp configure`. If this is successful, awesome!
Now you can build it: `node-gyp build`.

That should do it. If you were trying to install paper, now you can. Hooray!

If this doesn't work, or you have something to add, don't be shy! Please comment so we can all benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need cairo library which is bundled in GTK

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the most up-to-date information I've found](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup) on how to install the components required to run node-gyp which is in turn required to compile the code for canvas (and jsdom). I'm going to replicate it here in case the link dies. I have tested these instructions on my Win7 x64 machine and it worked first time.

---

On Windows XP/Vista/7, [node-gyp requires Python 2.7 and Visual Studio 2010](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation)

According to the readme file in [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422), *to ensure that your system has a supported configuration, uninstall the following products and then reinstall them in the order listed*:

1. [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express)
2. [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) Note: If you get error on installation, maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901279/windows-7-sdk-installation-failure)  will help you.
3. [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
4. [Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422)

On x64 environments, the last update in the list fixes errors about missing compilers and `error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found.`