# How to access MSSQL server data from Javascript / HTML5 webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, json, html

Can someone please point me in the direction of a good example of a way to access MSSQL Server data from a HTML5/Javascript webapp? I am having difficulty locating a relevant example that demonstrates this (must be asynchronous/secure).

I am currently waiting on a answer to issues with installation of the MSSQL Server driver for Node.js elsewhere on the SO, or else I'd be using that.

I'm new to web development, so the more detailed the better.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll need a web server to do the actual database connections/work. You mention Node.js, but are you open to anything? Java, Ruby, Python, Node.js?

Comment: It's not a good idea to expose your database directly to javascript calls because a hacker could write their own JS to make database submits. You'll always need a service layer between your client and your database.

Comment: Thanks guys, and yes @jasonscript & ian, I get that I need to create a service layer between the client js and server database. Node was the first and obvious choice to me, but I am still struggling with the perils of installing the MSSQL driver for Node.js on windows (see my issue/deadend [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21562038/1751090) ).I don't really want to deal with asp.net but if I have to ....I guess I have to. Can eaither of you suggest a webservice as an alternative to Node good for many concurrent users and async calls? Thanks guys

Comment: You can create a WCF and do async calls via ajax

Comment: @Bahamut, thanks. Not trying to use any more Microsoft products than I already have to...that was the first option I considered.