# Npm install zmq windows7

Tags: node.js, windows, msbuild, npm, zeromq

I'm trying to install zmq on windows 7 with npm, but it fails with this error:

```
>C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\zmq>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\  
npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild  
/MSBUILD : error MSB1009: 프로젝트 파일이 없습니다.  
스위치: build/binding.sln  
gyp ERR! build error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail  
ed with exit code: 1  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\  
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)  
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809: 12)  
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu  
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"  
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\zmq  
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29  
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1  
gyp ERR! not ok  
npm ERR! zmq@2.7.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.7.0 install script.  
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,  
npm ERR! not with npm itself.  
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild  
npm ERR! You can get their info via:  
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq  
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.  
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod  
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "zmq"  
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32  
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29  
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:  
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log  
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I saw a lot of posts about it but none of them provides me a solution.
I installed visual studio express and set the PYTHONPATH environment variable (I also tried to set the PYTHON variable, not working), as described here https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/wiki/Installation

I'm really stucked here, I appreciate any help, thank's in advance.

EDIT: when I run node-gyp rebuild manually in the console I got this :

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Bureau1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bureau1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bureau1\Desktop\app
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is installed?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 express

Comment: I'm trying to remove it and install 2013, as it's said here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node-gyp build error windows x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64)