# Node Webkit Unable to install SQLite3 Module

Tags: node.js, module, sqlite, node-webkit

I'm very new to Node.JS and Node WebKit. I am trying to install the SQLite3 package for Node WebKit by following the instructions that the site has given me

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3

I am in my directory with my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "description": "First attempt",
    "author": "Person",
    "main": "index.html",
    "window": {
        "toolbar": false,
        "width": 600,
        "height": 400
    },
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

And I did the first required command

```
npm install nw-gyp -g
```

which seems to have worked, then I tried to install the SQLite3 Module

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=$("0.12.3")
```

I also tried

```
npm install sqlite3 --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=x64 --target=0.12.3
```

But this is failing and the log wasn't terribly helpful

```
2623 verbose pkgid sqlite3@3.1.1
2624 verbose cwd C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit
2625 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
2626 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sqlite3" "--build-from-source" "--runtime=node-webkit" "--target_arch=ia32" "--target=$(0.12.3)"
2627 error node v4.2.5
2628 error npm  v2.14.12
2629 error code ELIFECYCLE
2630 error sqlite3@3.1.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
2630 error Exit status 1
2631 error Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.1 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
2631 error This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
2631 error not with npm itself.
2631 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2631 error     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
2631 error You can get their info via:
2631 error     npm owner ls sqlite3
2631 error There is likely additional logging output above.
2632 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
2633 verbose unbuild node_modules\sqlite3
2634 info preuninstall sqlite3@3.1.1
2635 info uninstall sqlite3@3.1.1
2636 verbose unbuild rmStuff sqlite3@3.1.1 from C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit\node_modules
2637 info postuninstall sqlite3@3.1.1
2638 silly gentlyRm C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit\node_modules\sqlite3 is being purged from base C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit
2639 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit\node_modules\sqlite3
2640 silly vacuum-fs purging C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit\node_modules\sqlite3
2641 silly vacuum-fs removing C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit\node_modules
2642 silly vacuum-fs finished vacuuming up to C:\PROG\NodeJS\Programs\NodeWebKit
```

Where do I start attempting to resolve this

*UPDATE*

This problem may be related to the nw-gyp. I ran

```
npm install nw-gyp -g
```

Which seemed ok but if I try to use it then I get an error, if I run

```
nw-gyp configure --target=0.12.3
```

I get an error

```
'nw-gyp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

*UPDATE 02*

I'm going to Install Visual Studio Express to see if this fixes it. This may take a long time

Comment: Could be windows related. I've only ever used sqlite3 on linux. That being said, have you check nw-gyp is installed in %AppData%/npm/ (as a cmd or batch file) and the module itself under %AppData%/npm/node_modules?

Comment: It is there I double checked inside C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm which has nw-gyp as well as nw-gyp.bat and then C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nw-gyp\gyp has gyp as well as gyp.bat

Comment: and %NODE_PATH% is set to %AppData%\npm\node_modules?

Comment: No, this is my first time hearing of NODE_PATH o_o

Comment: I set my environment using "set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\nodejs" and "set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\nodewebkit\nwjs-v0.12.3-win-x64"

Comment: looking at those instructions, they seem to be for a linux system! all paths and commands are for linux . Does it say somewhere its supported on windows?

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: The link you put in your post. I see lots of linux examples, some osx but no windows example or mention of windows. I just tried on windows and I get errors too.

Comment: I'm sure it's Windows though, they have Linux examples separately with the OSx ones and it's using the npm package which is platform independant

Comment: good point! Do you have a compatile compiler installed to build it? e.g. visual studio. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64)

Comment: I have Python 2.7 but I need Visual Studio?

Comment: Well, sqlite is built in c++. Under "On most linuxes" I see a bunch of c++ link and compile flags so I guess it's using gcc. On windows that's usually replaced by visual studio but sometimes mingw/gcc will do the job.

Comment: Wow, I guess I'll install Visual Studio. It's quite a beast of a download but if I'm going to do it I'll at least try do it right. Thanks for all your help I will put this on hold until the download is done

Comment: Good luck! beast indeed.  I don't see how else you will build sqlite on windows though (hope it;s not a wild goose chase). One last comment though ... Can you not use the prebuilt version? npm install sqlite3 works just fine for me (although I didn't try any sample code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problems as you did and I could fix it by doing the following.

Install Visual Studio Express 2012 or 2010. 
Afterwards Install Python and **make sure** that you set the build path. There is usually a option asking you to set the for you, if you use the installer.

Use the following command to install SQLite

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=x64 --target="0.12.3" --save
```

Don't forget the `--save` as it will save the installation to your package.json. This is necessary for node-webkit to find it.

**UPDATE**
With `echo %PATH%` in cmd you can see your path. Adding Python would look like this `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib` 
Depending on where you installed python

Comment: Hello, I've finally got VS Express Installed. I have Python 2.7 installed and in my path. What do I need to add to my path from Visual Studio?

Comment: It is not the path from visual studio. That one is not relevant. Have you tried installing it. Is it working? The Path you have to add is the system path

Comment: Wow it seems to have just installed with no problems after installing VS Express, I don't understand how but I'm just so stoked

Comment: Haven't tried to implement the module in my Project yet but that may be a nightmare of it's own, I appreciate the help