# Error installing elementor

Tags: node.js, protractor, npm-install, elementor

I am trying to install elementor(npm install -g elementor as admin) but I am getting a series of errors like:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yianna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elementor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
```

I am running webmanager while trying to install and I have tried to update the node-gyp to the latest.
What could cause this?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4047.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64) post.
it seems like Windows sdk was missing from my machhine.