# fsevents (pulled in by chokidar) in npm shrinkwrap causes build to fail on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, fsevents, windows-10-desktop, npm-shrinkwrap

OSX only `fsevents` is listed in the `npm` `shrinkwrap` because it's pulled in by `chokidar`. Our production is Linux based and it didn't cause any trouble there, obviously OSX developers are fine too, but it broke `npm install` on my Win x64 environment.

How can I fix that?

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\splive>npm install
(node:2888) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

> fsevents@1.0.8 install C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.8/fse-v1.0.8-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.8 and node@6.3.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2003, in GenerateOutput
    sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1762, in _GatherSolutionFolders
    return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
  File "C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1715, in _DictsToFolders
    for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14388
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\splive\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v48-win32-x64\\fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\splive\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v48-win32-x64" "--python=C:\\Python27\\python.exe" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v48-win32-x64\fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v48-win32-x64 --python=C:\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14388
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\splive\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v48-win32-x64\fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=C:\Users\User\Documents\splive\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v48-win32-x64 --python=C:\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm WARN install:fsevents@1.0.8 fsevents@1.0.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN install:fsevents@1.0.8 Exit status 1
```

complete output: http://pastebin.com/WNy0pmqK

Anyone encountered this? How to overcome this?

---

Info about my system:

I'm using Node.js 6.4 right now (tried to upgrade form 5.3 so it may help). Npm version is 3.10.5 although I tried to downgrade to 3.3.12 because certain npm issues suggested that. I'm on x64 Win 10 Insider latest Slow ring build.

---

This might be related but none of the solutions worked and it's not really about shrinkwrap: [node-gyp build error windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64)

Might be related git issues:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10768
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2679

Comment: Now it fails even if I delete fsevent manually form the shrinkwrap. Chokidar is a package which is pulled in transitively also. Anyone has an idea how to deal with this? Everyone is using now Mac?

Comment: Please comment your node, npm version and system if you suffer from the same thing so maybe we can figure out some patterns.

Comment: This `fsevents` is trippin' on Linux as well BTW. Ridiculous, Mac is like a plague

Comment: I'm having this exact issue on Windows 7 with Node 8.9.4 / npm 5.6.0. No macs or Linux used anywhere on this project. "npm install" doesn't install fsevents, but does add it to the shrinkwrap file. If I check that change in, it causes npm install to fail on the build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npm install --no-optional` to install your packages without adding `fsevents` to the shrinkwrap file. (If there are references to `fsevents` in there already, remove them manually.)

I discovered this option via another Stack Overflow question: [error fsevents@1.0.14 in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771017/error-fsevents1-0-14-in-windows-7)

Comment: That looks like a good solution, but unfortunately my main OS is Linux again for the last 2+ years so I cannot test this. I haven't ran into this specific one on Linux with the exact same codebase, although `fsevents` is not Linux compatible either. So theoretically it should be a problem there as well, but it never materialized.