# error fsevents@1.0.14 in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Hy... I'm trying to install webpack on windows 7 x64 by running this command :

```
npm install webpack -g
```

But then the my command prompt gave an error said "npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14"... I have been reading a loot sources on internet about this issue, for example :
installing windows package, using npm init bla bla, using npm shrinkwrap bla bla, deleting node-module directory and start initiializing it again, changing the node.js version, and so on...
but seems none of them suit me well...So is there any other way that I can try...??? Thank you so much... :)
I really apreciate your answer here.. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, the problem here is the HTTP fetch. Try using

```
npm install --no-optional.
```

It will work.You can read more about this  [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11632)

Comment: Thank you... I have solved that, but there are so many errors in my webpack.server.js...I need to post question again about that... 
Thanks again Mr. @Lav Kumar.. :)

Comment: The --no-optional argument will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with CI workflow script and even "--no-optional" was not working with ci

```
npm ci --no-optional
```

The above command only worked when I added the optional package as

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
}
```

in the package.json file