# Gyp build errors

Tags: node.js, npm, cloudant

I am currently using windows 10, node v7.10.0, npm v4.2.0 and trying to install the cloudant library using

```
npm install --save cloudant
```

could anyone help me figure out what is wrong? I've tried reinstalling node-gyp,
also tried

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

this is the error

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` 
failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Michael Vaquier\Documents\Wibicom\Wibismart-Bluemix-
App\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: have you tried one this step? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64#22536869

Comment: I've tried **--msvs_version=2012** yes, it unfortunately does not fix the issue