# binding.gyp not found (cwd: \node_modules\appium\node_modules\heapdump) while trying to load binding.gyp

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, node-modules, appium-android

I am trying to install appium using npm command.

Every attempt I am getting errors.

In the last attempt I refer below link:

[node-gyp build error windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64)

So to install appium in my windows 10 64 bit machine, I followed below steps:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global

npm install -g node-gyp-install

npm install appium
```

Getting Error as below:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\appium\node_modules\heapdump>if not
>   defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild ) gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\appium\node_modules\heapdump) while
>   trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack
>   Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\appium\node_modules\heapdump gyp ERR!
>   node -v v6.11.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0 gyp ERR! not ok
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32 `-- appium@1.7.1

The only problem with appium is with it's complex configuration.

If any one have working steps to install appium in windows then please share. It will really help

Any suggestion will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Do you have Python 2 installed? `node-gyp` requires it. I [had similar problems](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/converting-the-uselesscode-org-blog-to-a-static-site/#difficulties-in-the-process) a while back when I upgraded npm. Also, you said that you installed `node-gyp-install`, have you installed `node-gyp` as well?

Comment: Yes I have python 2.7.9 installed in my system. while using "npm install --global --production windows-build-tools " it again install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missed global tag for appium installation

```
npm install -g appium
```

so install in below steps:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global

npm install -g node-gyp-install

npm install -g node-gyp

npm install -g appium
```

Comment: Install globally `node-gyp` and all incriminated packages solved my problems