# NPM install fails with node-gyp / microtome

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I've tried just about everything I can think of it to resolve this error.

- X Clear npm cache
- X Blow away the repo and start fresh
- X Switch Node versions between v18.0.0, v16.15.0, v12.22.1
- X Reinstall NPM

Nothing has worked. What can I try next?

The Error:

```
583 error code 1
584 error path /Users/fuego/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/walletWatcher/node_modules/microtime
585 error command failed
586 error command sh -c node-gyp-build
587 error CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/node_modules/node-addon-api/src/nothing.o
587 error   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
587 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/microtime/src/microtime.o
588 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
588 error gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
588 error gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | arm64
588 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "/Users/fuego/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3"
588 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.15.0/node-v16.15.0-headers.tar.gz
588 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.15.0/node-v16.15.0-headers.tar.gz
588 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.15.0/SHASUMS256.txt
588 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.15.0/SHASUMS256.txt
588 error gyp info spawn /Users/fuego/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
588 error gyp info spawn args [
588 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/fuego/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
588 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
588 error gyp info spawn args   'make',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/fuego/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/walletWatcher/node_modules/microtime/build/config.gypi',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/fuego/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/fuego/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/fuego/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/fuego/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/fuego/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/fuego/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/walletWatcher/node_modules/microtime',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
588 error gyp info spawn args   'build',
588 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
588 error gyp info spawn args ]
588 error gyp info spawn make
588 error gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
588 error warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
588 error clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/walletWatcher/node_modules/microtime/node_modules/node-addon-api'
588 error make: *** [Release/obj.target/microtime/src/microtime.o] Error 1
588 error gyp ERR! build error 
588 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
588 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/fuego/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
588 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
588 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
588 error gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
588 error gyp ERR! command "/Users/fuego/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node" "/Users/fuego/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
588 error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/fuego/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/walletWatcher/node_modules/microtime
588 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
588 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
588 error gyp ERR! not ok
589 verbose exit 1
590 timing npm Completed in 5928ms
591 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1651610607893
592 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1651610610709
593 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1651610610710
594 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1651610610710
595 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1651610610717
596 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/microtime 1651610610750
597 verbose code 1
```

Comment: Do any of the answers on this similar question help? [node-gyp build error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21562038/979052)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mac M1 and Node 16, change the node version to 14, it should work.
You can use nvm to switch the node versions.

Example:

```
 nvm list
 nvm use V14.15.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing node-addon-api, simply use `npm i node-addon-api` to install it.

```
588 error clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/walletWatcher/node_modules/microtime/node_modules/node-addon-api'
```