# Mex setup for matlab Win8

Tags: windows, visual-studio, matlab, mex

I'm trying to setup mex in matlab and I got a message 
"No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. 
For a list of supported compilers, see
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012b/win64.html"  But this sdk is not suitable for WIn8. And I have already installed visual studio 2013. I don't understand why it can't find the compiler. Please help me.

Comment: I found solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901279/windows-7-sdk-installation-failure

Comment: Confirming the above is possible, I have win 8.1 with Matlab 2013a using Microsoft SDK 7.1 for compiling mex